# How to redirect from certain new site webpages back to some old site web pages

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, e-commerce

I have an **old** and **new** version of a website.  The new version is .php. and the previous was based on wordpress.  Currently it redirects to the new php page when the old domain is typed in. However, there a certain pages on the old site which are still required for the new site which do not load up.  Specifically, these are eCommerce /payment pages.

The issue arises when a "buy" button is pressed on a products page on the **new** site and rather than linking to the old ecommerce/payment page, it redirects to the **new** homepage.  To make matters worse, the wordpress panel login used for the **old** site doesn't load up so I'm concerned as to whether or not it is still there - considering how painstaking and expensive this was for me to have developed.

All in all could someone shed light please on:

- what the could be causing the issues of accessing the ecommerce pages and the **old** site wordpress login page coming up?
- how to redirect from the **new** site back to the **old** eCommerce pages if it's still possible?

Many thanks in advance for any solutions provided.